# Cache Condition not working based on Wordpress cookies

Tags: varnish

So I am trying to set my cache condition based on cookies found. I am using below code but the functionality is not working properly as the cookies page is getting cached for 24 hrs. Can any one take a look and let me know what the issue in below code of mine?

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~"(wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in|comment_author_)") {
       set cacheable = false;#versions less than 3
        beresp.ttl>0 is cacheable so 0 will not be cached
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    } else {
       set beresp.cacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl=300s;#cache for 24hrs
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your code is missing `set beresp` flag use below code and then test it will work perfectly.

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~"(wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in|comment_author_)") {
       set beresp.cacheable = false;#versions less than 3
        beresp.ttl>0 is cacheable so 0 will not be cached
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    } else {
       set beresp.cacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl=300s;#cache for 24hrs
    }
```